# Regex to match specific path with specific query param

Tags: javascript, regex, url, query-string

I'm struggling with creating regex to match URL path with query param that could be in any place.

For example URLs could be:

```
/page?foo=bar&target=1&test=1 <- should match
/page?target=1&test=2 <- should match
/page/nested?foo=bar&target=1&test=1 <- should NOT match
/page/nested?target=1&test=2 <- should NOT match
/another-page?foo=bar&target=1&test=1 <- should NOT match
/another-page?target=1&test=2 <- should NOT match
```

where I need to target param `target` specifically on `/page`

This regex works only to find the param `\A?target=[^&]+&*`.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
It is needed for a third-party tool that will decide on which page to run an experiment. It only accepts setup on their dashboard with regular experssion so I cannot use code tools like URL parser.

Comment: \/page\?.*target=([^&]+)

It will match in group 1 the content of **target**, in this case "1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General rule is that if you want to parse params, use URL parser, not a custom regex.

In this case you can use for instance:

```
# http://a.b/ is just added to make URL parsing work
url = new URL("http://a.b/page?foo=bar&target=1&test=1")
url.searchParams.get("target")
# => 1
url.pathname
# => '/page'
```

And then check those values in ifs:

```
url = new URL("http://a.b/page?foo=bar&target=1&test=1")

url = new URL("http://a.b/page?foo=bar&target=1&test=1")
if (url.searchParams.get("foo") && url.pathname == '/page' {
  # ...
}
```

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

**EDIT**

If you have to use regex try this one:

```
\/page(?=\?).*[?&]target=[^&\s]*(&|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V7yi8n/2)

Explanation:

- `\/page(?=\?)` - matches path (starts with `/` then `page` then lookahead for `?`)
- `.*[?&]target=[^&\s]*($|&)` matches param name `target`:

  - located anywhere (preceded by anything `.*`)
  - `[?&]` preceded with `?` or `&`
  - followed by its value (=[^&\s]*)
  - ending with end of params (`$`) or another param (`&`)

Comment: it’s needed for a tool that will decide on which page to run an experiment. It only accepts setup on their dashboard this way.

Comment: so I don’t have an option here

Comment: Updated regex will match `/page?foo=bar?target=1&test=1` with 2 `?`

Comment: What do you mean? Shouldn't it match?

Comment: No it shouldn't match because `/page?foo=bar?target=1&test=1` has `?` twice.

Comment: I assume it's a valid URL params string

Comment: @Kosmetika - you should edit your question and update it with the information in these comments. mrzasa's suggestion to use `new URL` **is** the most natural response, because your question doesn't mention the limitations that prevent you from doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a regex then you may use:

```
/\/page\?(?:.*&)?target=[^&]*/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2DCvXd/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\/page\?`: Match text `/page?`:
- `(?:.*&)?`: Match **optional** text of any length followed by `&`
- `target=[^&]*`: Match text `target=` followed by 0 or more characters that are not `&`