# Angular Proxy to Backend Match API Path with Specific Query Parameter

Tags: angular, proxy

I'm trying to proxy backend call to API with specific query parameter. Say, API path is `/path/to/api?param1=foo&param2=bar`, and I need to proxy only requests with `param2=bar`. Proxying calls to `/path/to/api` without or with any query parameters is easy and not my case.

I started digging from [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server), but it containts only basic examples. Then I found [this article](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#context-matching), where it's said that I can use custom matcher function, but according to [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1896#issuecomment-243472868) it's not supported in Angular. Then I visited [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) and found that custom matcher could probably be passed to proxy config context property. Though, I can't figure out how to use it in Angular proxy config, since it has another schema. [This article](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#path-examples) seems to have the most close hint to construct the path I need, and I played with different options, though none of them really worked. I figured out that path uses either [micromatch](https://github.com/micromatch/micromatch) or [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) format, but this knowledge didn't help me as well. I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57419840/regex-to-match-specific-path-with-specific-query-param) to similar question and played a bit with suggested regex, adapting it to my case, but again with no luck.

```
// ...
"**/path/to/api?*param2=bar*": {
  "target": "https://localhost:4200",
  "secure": false,
  "pathRewrite": () => "/mocks/api.mock.json"
},
// ...
```

This is one of many approaches I tried, and it doesn't proxy needed request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `pathRewrite` callback to retrieve information about url path.

Example:

```
"**/v1/myApi": {
  "pathRewrite": (path) => {
      if (path.includes('param=bar')) {
          return "/mocks/response1.mock.json";
      }
      return "/mocks/response2.mock.json";
  }
}
```

Comment: How can you add the callback if the proxy-config file is a .json?