# Regex to match specific query parameter at arbitray position

Tags: regex

I have an NGINX config where the following string is matched:

```
  map "QUERY:${query_string},HEADER:${http_x_canary_target},COOKIE:${http_cookie}" $app_version {
   // regex goes here
}
```

I want to match the `query_string` part by looking if a specific query param called `canary-target` with a specific value `v1` is present at an arbitrary position. The rest of the string (i.e. `,HEADER:...,COOKIE:...`) shall not be considered. **I have only access to the full string, not to the substring.**

So the following examples should match (because `canary-target=v1` is present at an arbitrary position in the query string):

```
QUERY:canary-target=v1,HEADER:xxx,COOKIE:xxx
QUERY:foo=bar&canary-target=v1,HEADER:xxx,COOKIE:xxx
QUERY:canary-target=v1&foo=bar,HEADER:xxx,COOKIE:xxx
QUERY:foo=bar&canary-target=v1&baz=baq,HEADER:xxx,COOKIE:xxx
```

Whereas the following shouldn't (because `v11` is not a valid value for `canary-target`):

```
QUERY:canary-target=v11,HEADER:xxx,COOKIE:xxx
QUERY:foo=bar&canary-target=v11,HEADER:xxx,COOKIE:xxx
QUERY:canary-target=v11&foo=bar,HEADER:xxx,COOKIE:xxx
QUERY:foo=bar&canary-target=v11&baz=baq,HEADER:xxx,COOKIE:xxx
```

My current regex is `QUERY:.*canary-target=v1&?,HEADER:.*,COOKIE:.*`, but that only matches the first two  examples and not the last two (where `canary-target` is being followed by additional query params).

The regex `QUERY:.*canary-target=v1&?.*,HEADER:.*,COOKIE:.*` also does not work because it matches all examples, when it shouldn't (because only `v1` should be considered allowed values for `canary-target`).

I already found a similar question here: [Regex to match specific path with specific query param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57419840/regex-to-match-specific-path-with-specific-query-param)

But that does not help me because it only considers a URL, which, in my case, is followed/concatenated by other strings (`,HEADER:...,COOKIE:...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is - use a test for word boundary after the `v1` like

```
QUERY:.*canary-target=v1\b.*,HEADER:.*,COOKIE:.*
```

It makes sure the `v1` isn't followed by a digit (or a character), thus matching the boundary between the `1` and `,` or `&` (non word characters).

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BK8cHS/1).

(But it should be noted that this places strict demands on the format of the string tested.)